# Vagrant box running CentoOS on Windows is really slow - any ideas to speed it up

Tags: magento, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I have vagrant installed on my Windows 7 machine, currently it has an installation hooked up with VirtualBox & a CentoOS install.

While it everything does work, and the server is all configured and the PHP is running ok it really does seem to crawl. I currently have a development version of Magento on here and it is much much slower than I would expect. Occassionally some pages (the checkout ones) can take up-to 2 minutes to process and bring the user to the next page, obviously this makes development very frustrating and slow.

Can anyone suggest any ideas on the best way to optimise my vagrant box?

p.s i've not set this up myself so i am not fully aware of all its configs/settings etc...

Comment: http://desmart.com/blog/windows-vagrant-puphpet-winnfsd this post really helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has a lot of files, and Virtualbox file share mechanism between Linux and Windows is very slow. Workaround is to use samba saerver on guest and mount it on host.